# nested form rails update duplicate result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a problem to update the attributes of a nested form. I send this params to my controllers. But

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"sdfdsf", "office"=>{"worker_id"=>"5", "partecipants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"74", "is_presence"=>"true", "person_id"=>"83"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"75", "is_presence"=>"false", "person_id"=>"84"}}}, "commit"=>"salva", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"etsw/course/offices", "id"=>"39"}`

I have duplicate result why? I use rails 3.2. My modal below there is the logic not all point because is for a office project

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_protected :id
    belongs_to :worker, class_name: 'Worker', foreign_key: :worker_id
    has_many :partecipants, class_name: 'Partecipant', foreign_key: :office_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for: partecipants,:allow_destroy => true


  end

  class Partecipant < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :id, is_presence, office_id, person_id

    belongs_to :office, class_name: 'Office', foreign_key: :office_id
    belongs_to :person, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :person_id

  end
```

I use rails 3.2..
I use rails 3.2..I try to use strong parameters but the result is the same

```
@office.update_attributes(office_params)

  private
    def office_params
      params.require(:office).permit(:worker_id, partecipants_attributes: [:id, :is_presence, :person_id])
    end
```

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information and some code.

Comment: Please provide the update method and any related ones

Comment: You mentioned about rails 3.2 three times along the post. Please take at least a quick look to the posts before posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. When I create a office there is an after_save that create the partecipants and every time i save the nested form this active the after save function